# Error 20580 occurred at disk power-on lifetime

Tags: hard-drive

I just put new discs to my server and I want to create raid but during initial rebuild (raid 5) I get disc failure. After that I have problem to check SMART parameter of that disc. After reboot I get something like this:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-169-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA HDWG440
Serial Number:    X3G0A0X7FZ0G
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 cd8cb9942
Firmware Version: 0601
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Dec 25 00:29:23 2023 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Thresholds failed: Connection timed out

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 421) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       8295
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       12
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       15 (Min/Max 11/15)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   001   001   ---    Old_age   Always       -       20582
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       17170433
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       12
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       500
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 20580 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 20580 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12 hours (0 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 00 0f 00 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000000f = 15

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:12.972  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 10 00 00 40 00      12:04:12.972  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:12.429  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 00 00      12:04:12.414  READ LOG EXT
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:11.972  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 20579 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12 hours (0 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 00 0f 00 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000000f = 15

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:11.972  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 10 00 00 40 00      12:04:11.553  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 00 00      12:04:11.540  READ LOG EXT
  60 01 00 10 00 00 40 00      12:04:11.114  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:10.705  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 20578 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12 hours (0 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 00 10 00 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000010 = 16

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 10 00 00 40 00      12:04:11.114  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:10.705  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 00 00      12:04:10.689  READ LOG EXT
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:10.689  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 00 00 00 40 00      12:04:10.237  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 20577 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12 hours (0 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 00 0f 00 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000000f = 15

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 00      12:04:10.689  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 00 00 00 40 00      12:04:10.237  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 a0 be c0 40 00      12:04:09.769  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 00 00      12:04:09.756  READ LOG EXT
  60 08 00 a0 be c0 40 00      12:04:08.845  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 20576 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12 hours (0 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 00 a7 be c0 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00c0bea7 = 12631719

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 a0 be c0 40 00      12:04:08.845  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 00 00      12:04:08.831  READ LOG EXT
  60 08 00 a0 be c0 40 00      12:04:07.933  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 00 00      12:04:07.921  READ LOG EXT
  60 08 00 a0 be c0 40 00      12:04:07.897  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        12         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I assume main error is this:

> Error 20580 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12 hours (0 days + 12 hours)
> When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.`

I just have bad luck and I need to return this disc or it can be some connection problem and I should go to visit my server?

/Edit
In dmesg I have error like this:

> [34480.464934] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 8 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

Comment: You didn't do the classic mistake that you put different disks in there? when you add a disk to a raid set it has to be the same as the ones which where already there, if I'm correct

Comment: I create totally new raid array. With new discs. After first failure I tried again but still with the same discs.

Answer (score 0):

SMART indicates that the drive is dead. What I'm seeing is (for instance)  `Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00c0bea7 = 12631719` which indicates that the data being read has a bad block CRC. Infant mortality, return for replacement.